# Send keep-alive message in php for SSE

Tags: php, jquery, server-sent-events

I'm using server-send events in order to display a console output in my web interface. My problem is that I can't seem to have a persistant connection when the delay between messages is too long. I'm not exactly sure how I can set this timeout to a different value (because after around 2 minutes the eventsource make a new request, and I want to avoid that).

Another idea would be to send keep alive messages from my PHP, but I only want those in case of no activity from my process. Send a default message every minute should work ok for my purpose, but I'm not sure on how to do that. I've seen a lots of solutions including a `sleep`in a forever running loop, but that would mean that my php process is interrupted during that time, and this is not something I want (obviously).

Here is my current php loop :

```
        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse ( function () use ($commands) {

        $handle = popen ( "\"$commands\"", "r" );
        if (ob_get_level () == 0) {
            ob_start ();
        }
        while ( ! feof ( $handle ) ) {
            $buffer = fgets ( $handle );
            $buffer = trim ( htmlspecialchars ( $buffer ) );

            echo 'data: ' .  $buffer  . "\n\n";

            ob_flush ();
            flush ();
        }
        echo 'data: ' . "ENDSTREAM\n\n";

        ob_flush ();
        flush ();
        pclose ( $handle );
        ob_end_flush ();

    } );

    $response->headers->set ( 'Content-Type', 'text/event-stream' );
    $response->headers->set ( 'Cach-Control', 'no-cache' );
    $response->headers->set ( 'Connection', 'keep-alive' );
```

If anyone has any pointers on how to achieve what I want, I'd gladly take them!

Comment: If anyone's interested, I solved the problem setting up a timeout in the messages (with `echo "retry: $timeout" . PHP_EOL;`)rather than sending a keep-alive message.